# SQL query to count the number of rows per month with data in Unix TimeStamp format

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, unix-timestamp

In my Mysql database I have a column that stores the date values ​​in Unix TimeStamp (type / BigInt, milliseconds). I need to write a query that allows me to count the number of lines for each month (regardless of the year).

Table:

```
    +-------+----------------+
    |   id  |    Startdata   |
    +-------+----------------+
    |     1 |  1580841222491 |  
    |     2 |  1580841235885 |  
    |     3 |  1580841235872 |  
    |     4 |  1580843242865 |  
    |     5 |  1580841134857 | 
    |     6 |  1580841334855 | 
    |     7 |  1580842252695 | 
    |     8 |  1580844236845 | 
       ...         ... 
    +-------+----------------+
```

Desired return:

```
+-------+-------+
| count | month |
+-------+-------+
|     4 |     1 |  
|     1 |     2 |  
|     6 |     3 |  
|    51 |     4 |  
|    21 |     5 | 
|    29 |     6 | 
|    41 |     7 | 
|    18 |     8 | 
|    21 |     9 | 
|    11 |    10 | 
|    38 |    11 |
|    23 |    12 |
+-------+-------+
```

function UNIX_TIMESTAMP does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`from_unixtime` allows you to specify the format of the output as well. In your case, `%m` is all you need.

```
select from_unixtime(Startdata/1000,"%m"), count(*)
from t
group by from_unixtime(Startdata/1000,"%m")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the below -

```
select month(date(from_unixtime(floor(Startdata/1000)))) as month_value,count(*) as cnt
from tablename
group by month(date(from_unixtime(floor(Startdata/1000))))
```

Note: If your MySql version is 8+ then you don't need the floor function

Comment: I tested it on MySQL 5.7, it works without `FLOOR` too. https://phpize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=2aa3f57a1e9e59e3b5c86c3061603121&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev, that's great!!

Answer (score 1):

The `Startdata` column in your table in milliseconds, so you need divide it by 1000 to convert into seconds. So query will be:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS `count`, 
    MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(Startdata/1000)) AS `month`
FROM `mytable`
GROUP BY `month`;
```

Live example [here](https://phpize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=d70a2e9f2a355eb71dfaad274c4bf12d&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)